# GTK interface structure: Why is it built as casting interface?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

GTK3 provides functions, that make casting necessary. As in

```
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0,0,0,0)
```

However, this method will always take a grid. So why wouldn't the cast be inside the function? The call would become:

```
gtk_grid_attach(grid, button, 0,0,0,0)
```

And would therefore be much shorter and easier readable (because no redundancy).

edit:

Due to the discussion in the comments, I'll try to make my question more clear using the example from David Ranieri below

Given the code:

```
 typedef struct {char *sound;} animal_t;
 typedef struct {animal_t animal; char *name;} dog_t;
 typedef struct {animal_t animal;} cat_t;

 #define DOG(animal) (dog_t *)animal
 #define CAT(animal) (cat_t *)animal
```

There are two ways to implement the function `dog_print_name` *without* loosing the typecheck-mechanism. In the example below I will hand over a `cat`, where a dog is expected.

(1)

```
 void dog_print_name(dog_t *dog)
 {
     puts(dog->name);
 }

 int main(){
   // ...
   dog_print_name(DOG(cat)); // perfom type check here
                             // and fail on 'cat'
 }
```

(2)

```
 void dog_print_name(void *dog)
 {
   dog_t *dog_ = DOG(dog); // check performed
                  // will fail, if 'dog' is a cat.
   puts(dog->name);
 }

 int main(){
   // ...
   dog_print_name(cat); // no check performed here
 }
```

These two pieces of code being given, what is the reason one would choose implementation (1) over implementation (2)?
The goal is to get a warning / error on a call where `dog` is expected, but `cat` is given.

Answer (score 1):

It's needed because C doesn't handle polymorphism. It can't check if that argument's type is valid based on the class hierarchy. So the macro triggers a check for that, and also make sure that even if you stored your pointer in the right pointer type, the content it points to (a GObject-derived object) uses the right type.

Here, `grid` has the right type, but not the right content. Making an explicit check makes debugging much easier.

```
GtkGrid *grid = gtk_image_new(); 
GtkButton *button = gtk_button_new();
gtk_grid_attach(grid, button, 0,0,0,0); // Won't catch early the fact that grid is a GtkImage, not a GtkGrid.
```

Also, most of the times, you just declare everything as a pointer to a GtkWidget. This is because depending on which methods you call, the class they come from may be different, so you'll need to cast anyway.

```
GtkWidget *grid = gtk_grid_new(); 
GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new();
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0,0,0,0); // WILL check at runtime that grid is a GtkGrid.
gtk_grid_remove_row(GTK_GRID(grid), 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(grid), button);
```

Comment: I understand, that a cast is necessary. I'm aiming for: why is the cast not moved inside the function `gtk_grid_attach`? Like this: `gtk_grid_attach(void * grid,  .... ){ GtkGrid * tmp = GTK_GRID(grid); /*...*/ }`

Comment: I don't really know. Why does every C function doesn't get a `void *` instead of a typed pointer then? Probably because you want the type system to still do some checks for you at compile time. That's also cleaner API, as IMHO `void *` everywhere would be a nightmare to hande, as expectations on input wouldn't be as clear.

Comment: More on this: https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/gui_toolkit_guides/gtk+_gnome_application_development/z105.html

Comment: "Probably because you want the type system to still do some checks for you at compile time." Using a void * in the parameter list would not disable any current language feature. It would just move it 2 execution rows  later (also see the discussion with David's example). I checked the link, but I couldn't see the answer to my question.

Comment: Using `void *` would prevent type checks _at compile time_, which are not equivalent to the macros that perform checks _at run time_.

Comment: liberforce, the current way of casting is also a runtime-only check. Indeed, the parameters are typed, but the parameter is only validated at runtime. Ergo, in most cases (because `GtkWidget *` is used) all checks only happen at runtime.